Visual Studio raises an error adding endpoints with the wizard
Using Visual Studio 2022, I want to generate the API using the wizard for endpoints. The first endpoint is fine. When I create the second one, I get this error.

error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'HypnoPlatform.Controllers.ClientEndpoints.MapClientEndpoints(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder)' and 'HypnoPlatform.Controllers.ClientEndpoints.MapClientEndpoints(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder)'


In order to compile the solution and generate a new endpoint, I have to comment in the Program.cs the reference to this endpoint like
// app.MapClientEndpoints();

and then I can continue. When I run the application, sometimes I get the same error but with all the endpoints.

The CS0121 error ("The call is ambiguous") arises when the compiler cannot resolve which method overload to use due to identical or conflicting signatures. This document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/overload-resolution#ambiguous-overloads) outlines scenarios that may trigger this error. I suggest you to check if there are two MapClientEndpoints(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IEndpointRouteBuilder) function signatures in the ClientEndpoints class.
